# Deploy gzip content on Amazon S3

Tags: deployment, amazon-s3, gzip, s3cmd

I use gzip compression for Amazon S3. I gzip HTML, JS, CSS files and keep images unchanged.

I sync everything using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd):

```
s3cmd sync --cf-invalidate ./deploy s3://n12v.com
```

Unfortunately, this doesn’t set `Content-Encoding: gzip` to all necessary files.

I need to find all updated gzip files and set `Content-Encoding: gzip` for each one of them. The best solution I could came up with:

- find all gzipped files by running `gzip --test filepath` on every one
- `s3cmd put --add-header='Content-Encoding: gzip' filepath s3://n12v.com/filepath`, e.g. upload files *again* just to add a header.

This is very ad-hoc solution, is there any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same type of issue so I wrote [s3tup](https://github.com/HeyImAlex/s3tup). Unfortunately it doesn't offer anything like s3cmd's cf-invalidate flag (yet), but it makes configuring while rsyncing a lot easier. You'd write a config file that looks something like this.

```
# config.yml
---
bucket: n12v.com
rsync: ./deploy
key_config:
  - patterns: ['*.html', '*.css', '*.js']
    content_encoding: gzip
```

And then rsync from the command line like this.

```
$ s3tup config.yml --rsync_only
```

It's still early in development but maybe you'll find it useful.